# Fiori Launchpad : could not run custom App -Found negative cache

Tags: deployment, sapui5, sap-fiori

i deployed an application on SAPUI5 Repository, when i added it to Fiori launchpad the app could not start and it's giving me the following error while debugging :

```
Uncaught Error: found in negative cache: 'com/emi/Component.js' from sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zstatic/Component.js: 404 - NOT FOUND
```

com.emi is my sapui5 Component specified in LPD_CUST

zstatic is the name of my app

Does anyone have any information about the cause of this ? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i finally found where the error is, the problem is resolved by adding a / before application url like this

```
/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zstatic/
```